# App from Mac app store not installing

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

I am trying to reinstall an app I purchased some time ago. It is not installing. In the console I get the following message:

```
LaunchServices: Failed to create bundleProxy for bundle com.trankyman.aText
```

Answer (score 2):

`aText` MAS version doesn't work El Capitan due to sandboxing. You can switch to non-MAS version for free, by downloading http://www.trankynam.com/atext/downloads/aText.dmg

Check their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/aText/)

> I am sorry for the late responding. Unfortunately aText Mac App Store version does not work on OSX 10.11 El Capitan. This is not fixable.
>   aText 'full' version (not sandboxed) still works with OSX 10.11 El Capitan.
>   Please switch to non-MAS version for free, by downloading http://www.trankynam.com/atext/downloads/aText.dmg

You can also check their [video](https://youtu.be/2cCSTwdo8bs) link on their [website](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am unable to switch because I need the MAS version of the app to switch. And I cannot install the version.

Comment: @Raymond, If you have installed the MAS version once, you don't need to reinstall it. Just install the trial version. Check the video link I just added.